# How to Add Condition Check to Determine which Template will be used in Transactional Emails?

Tags: email-templates, transactional-mail

I am  trying to modify my email template to generate different product information *based on customer group*. As in, if a customer belongs to Group A, load `modified.phtml`, else load `default.phtml`.

Specifically, I am working with the New Order email template where the base transactional email template calls `{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}`, which loads the template file in `/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/email/order/items.phtml`.

This template eventually calls `echo $this->getItemHtml($_item)`.

From what I can tell, this loads the template file `/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml`, which outputs the template information to print each item's content (SKU, Name, Price, etc) in the table.

**This is what I'm trying to accomplish:**

```
$customerGroupId    = $this->getCustomerGroupId();
$customerGroupName  = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($customerGroupId)->getCustomerGroupCode();
if($customerGroupName = 'A') {
    // How to getItemHtml from different template?
} else {
    echo $this->getItemHtml($_item)
}
```

I assume that I will need to add reference to my `modified.phtml` in the `/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/sales.xml` file like so:

```
<sales_email_order_items>
    <block type="sales/order_email_items" name="items" template="email/order/items.phtml">
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_default</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
        // modified.phtml reference here?
```

**Can I make `getItemHtml` specify a different template?**

Or is there a different way I need to be approaching this?

I could replace the `{{layout handle...}}` with a `{{block...}}` call and put all of the template information within my `if... else...` blocks, but this seems very hacky. Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: I think you should have two different blocks with two templates in your page which you will add with xml reference file and then you will just call the appropriate block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the `itemHtml` depends upon the customer group. You can achieve that in layout file using a helper method.

```
<sales_email_order_items> 
     <block type="sales/order_email_items" name="items" template="email/order/items.phtml">
         <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_default</block><template helper="mymodule/data/myFunction"/></action>
```

Then create myFunction in your helper file

```
 app/code/{local|community}/yourNamespace/yourModule/helper/Data.php.
```

Use the below code

### Update :

```
public function myFunction()
{
    $customerGroupName = '';
    if($customerGroupId = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/sales_order_create')->getQuote()->getCustomerGroupId()):
        $customerGroupName = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($customerGroupId)->getCustomerGroupCode();
    elseif(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()):
        $customerGroupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
        $customerGroupName = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($customerGroupId)->getCustomerGroupCode();
    endif;
    if($customerGroupName == 'General') { 
       return 'email/order/items/order/default.phtml'; 
    } else { 
      return 'email/order/items/order/another.phtml';
    }
 }
```

That's it.

Comment: I got a `Fatal error: Call to undefined method MyNamespace_MyModule_Helper_Data::getCustomerGroupId() in .../Helper/Data.php on line 5`. Is it trying to find the method in _my_ helper?

Comment: Create an custom module and load that function through that

Comment: I've created a custom Module named Emailbygroup. It appears to call the Helper correctly when an email is sent, but my helper acts like it is looking for a method `getCustomerGroupId` within my `Emailbygroup/Helper/Data.php` file.

Comment: Get customer group id from order

Comment: @travisw check by updated code.

Comment: @travisw update the answer to get the customer group id admin order creation